# Opening app store page to rate my app

Tags: ios, objective-c

pretty new to this but I know I can use `itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idAPP_ID` as a link to my app. I'm not sure how to use this in my code though. How do I add this link to a button?

I understand this is also for iOS 7. Is there an older style link I have to use to get it working for versions prior?

Comment: Use `SKStoreProductViewController` to show the App Store page of an app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `openURL` to open the URL when a button is tapped. [UIApplication Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL:).

```
-(IBAction)appStoreButton:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id653287635"]];
}
```

Comment: Won't that just open the US site?

Comment: @trojanfoe This will open the App Store and load the application in which ever Country/Region's App Store the user is using as long as your application is for sale in that Country/Region.

Comment: Why not keep the user in your app by using `SKStoreProductViewController`?

Comment: @rmaddy I agree that this is a good alternative but it's not what the question was asking. I personally use Appirater to encourage users to rate my apps: https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater